# File tagger for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, file-management

I'm looking for a program that:

- can tag files
- can filter files by tag(s)
- is gratis
- runs on Microsoft Windows
- does not alter the file, or the filename (unlike [TagSpaces](http://www.tagspaces.org/)).

Ideally:

- compatible with OS X and Linux as well.
- can relocate files automatically if the folder has changed.

I don't want to use Windows' built-in tagging system, nor Mendeley Desktop.